# Laravel, error de versiones para hacer composer update

Tags: laravel, git

estoy intentando de correr un proyecto en laravel pero tengo el tipico error de que no encuentra el archivo artisan en el proyecto, y tengo entendido que para ello debo hacer composer install y composer update. El tema es que al ejecutar esas dos lineas en la consola me encuentro con un error de requerimientos de versiones de php.

```
Problem 1
    - niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf[v4.0.0, ..., v4.1.0] require mpdf/mpdf ^8.0 -> satisfiable by mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.0-RC1, ..., v8.0.11].
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.0-RC1, ..., v8.0.3] require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 -> your php version (8.0.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.4, ..., v8.0.7] require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 || ~7.4.0 -> your php version (8.0.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.8, ..., v8.0.9] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - mpdf/mpdf[v8.0.10, ..., v8.0.11] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's gd extension.
    - Root composer.json requires niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf ^4.0 -> satisfiable by niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf[v4.0.0, v4.1.0].
```

Que puedo hacer yo para solucionar este inconveniente?

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate en la tercera línea,

```
require php ^5.6 || ~7.0.0 || ~7.1.0 || ~7.2.0 || ~7.3.0 -> your php version (8.0.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Te aclara que las versiones de PHP requeridas para este módulo son versiones anteriores a la que tienes instalada (mayores a 5.6 hasta la última versión de 5.X, 7.0.0, 7.1.0, 7.2.0 y 7.3.0).

Mi recomendación es que instales PHP 7.3.0, que parece ser la versión más aceptada por el resto de los módulos. Y si algún módulo llega a faltar, pues toca instalarlo.